# Can any element in a coset be the representative of that coset?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

We know that
aH = bH iff a is in bH or b is in aH.
Does this mean that any element of a coset can be its representative? I.e. can 'b' be called as the coset representative of aH, if b is also in aH?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: Sure, it can. Every element of the equivalence class of an equivalence relation is a representative of that class.

Comment: Thanks! Made the idea of cosets much clear!

Comment: I believe that of your is more a terminological doubt. I suggest you to brush the concept of equivalence relation and partition in equivalence classes.